# Change CSS in Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

Good morning,

I'm doing slim for the first time on a small personal project and I'm having some difficulties, if you can help me :-)

I have a logo, I want to modify its CSS, once modified in the project, it does not update it for me when I launch it. Knowing that the CSS of the logo is in a global.scss file, however, when I modify this file and launch the project with npm start, the modification does not appear. Using DevTools, I see that the css is in a __layout.svelte-2b134d5e.css file. I am however sure that the global file is the same, the same tag and even the one that surrounds it are the same visible on the __layout.svelte-2b134d5e.css. I think it's generated, but I can't find how to do it. If you can help me.

THANKS

I have updated, relaunched the project but no change in the logo even having updated the global.scss file

change css and reload the project

Comment: With `npm start` you mean `npm run dev`? How did you enable `.scss` support? Where is the file imported?